# time.LoadLocation() gives unknown timezone for US/Pacific-New timezone

Tags: go, timezone

`Go version: 1.14.2`

`Operating system: Linux (Ubuntu)`

I am working on a dynamic timezone based system in which user can set the timezone. I have a user who set the timezone to US/Pecific-New. For this timezone, the golang time package gives following error:

`unknown time zone US/Pacific-New`

I have researched on this and found that time package loads the timezone from the local system having file paths:

`/usr/share/zoneinfo`

`/usr/local/go/lib/time`

On these paths, on my local system as well as on staging Pacific-New is missing on both locations.

Is there a way to get Pacific-New on these locations ?

Comment: [some background info](http://catless.ncl.ac.uk/Risks/13.87.html#subj1) - seems like `go` did the reasonable thing not to include this time zone?

Comment: @MrFuppes not very sure about this. Since the article was pulished in 1992, it has been 28 years and golang came in 2010. Not sure if this is considered.

Comment: well, as I get it, this time zone never came to use up until now (and likely won't in the future), so I think it is reasonable not to include it in the first place. The IANA tz database is another thing; for example it also contains names like EST, HST and MST, which strictly aren't time zones but UTC offsets of certain time zones during a certain period of the year. They're just there for historical reasons.

Answer (score 4):

`US/Pacific-New` was never a "real" time zone and should not be selected on any system.

It was created to reflect a potential change to Pacific time that was never enacted into law.  The idea at the time was that there would be a time zone ready in advance of the change.  However, since the bill wasn't enacted this turned out to be a failed experiment.  The TZDB no longer tries to create zones in speculative anticipation of future changes, but only adds or updates them when they are official or otherwise imminent.

Ultimately, `US/Pacific-New` was only ever a link to `US/Pacific` and then later updated as a link to the preferred form of `America/Los_Angeles` The last TZDB release to include such a link for `US/Pacific-New` was 2020a.

From the 2020b release notes:

> The long-obsolete files **pacificnew**, systemv, and yearistype.sh have been removed from the distribution.  (Thanks to Tim Parenti.)

You can read more about the long storied history with this link entry by searching [the `NEWS` file](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/NEWS) in the TZDB for "Pacific-New" and "pacificnew", and by reading [the 2020a version of the `pacificnew` file from before it was deleted](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2020a/pacificnew).

As far as practical advice, don't set `US/Pacific-New` on any system.  It is no longer a valid time zone identifier.  The whole system will be affected by this.  Switch to `America/Los_Angeles` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than `time.LoadLocation()` you can use [`time.LoadLocationFromTZData()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocationFromTZData) which loads a location from the contents of a timezone file, which can contain whatever timezones you like.

You will need a correctly formatted timezone file with the timezones you wish to use, perhaps based on whatever you have in `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.